# Angular JS - Destroy issue clean scope in global way by $destroy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i'm using angular 1.4.8 version

My App are complex and have a lot of directives which nested each others, I want to prevent a memory leaks in case when the developers are not cleaning after them self in creation of a custom directives,
My target is to ensure a clean for scopes in a global way.

Scenario:
I have a multiple scope which nested inside each others (some of the are isolate), all of them are listening to the angular '$destroy' event.

When I  call  to  $destroy() for the main scope all the clean logic running successfully for this main scope and all its child scope $$destroyed flag are set to true cause of this angular code:

[angular destroyChildScope function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xDX.png)

But if I want to perform a full destroy for all child scopes when the main parent become destroyed, then I try to call to $destroy() inside the angular '$destroty' event for each child scope.
The problem is:  when the event is fired for the children scope then the $$destroyed flag It's already set to true(as mentioned before) for all the children scopes and the $destroy function logic not running at all for the children's scopes cause of this angular destroy implement:

[angular destroy function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdUOa.png)

1. Why angular scope concept not include this feature build-in? what do I missing in angular scope concept?
2. What is the best way to achieve that?
3. Does recursion seeking for lowest child scope then calling to destroy() upward will be good enough solution?
4. Why  angular not clean $parent,  $watches, $listeners etc.. for child scope as I excepted, but do it only for the main parent scope?

I read a few  tutorials which directive that angular are disconnect the scope chain from the scopes hierarchy and make it eligible for GC by the destroy function logic, 
But in reality I encounter in some cases that child scopes  still have reference to the destroyed parent scopes by its '$parent' property or by the prototype of ChildScope function  which prevent it from clean by GC.

What could be the reason?

Thank you in advance…

Comment: angular does destroy all the scopes for you. can you create a plunker where it is not getting destroyed

Comment: in my case it's only change the flag $$destroyed to true for the child scopes but not remove all this scopes (the scopes still visible in chrome profile snapshot which mean there are still in memory) and they watchers and other property not become null as the main scope how fire destroy first

Comment: can you please create a plunker.. would be really interested in having a look

Comment: Sorry for the late response i found that the memory leaks happen only in my old chrome version which is 38V. after upgrading to 46V there isn't memory leaks for the scopes anymore in the profiler.


it will cause random memory leak only on chrome old version.
i found a solution for old chrome: to call the destroy function from the lowest child upward to the original target scope. it's solve the memory leak, but i think upgrading the chrome is better than doing this workaround, which it's against  angular scope concept.

Comment: here is the a plunker which could simulate my App logic:
http://embed.plnkr.co/39l9bsV9PdS7bhcoqcrn/